# Has anyone had problems with scala code-completion in IDEA when using sbt?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I recently switched to sbt (which I completely dig) and as soon as I started to compile and run tests from sbt, code completion in IDEA seems to come and go... very strange.

Comment: -1 Not a programming question, not enough information to glean much of an answer. Try the IntelliJ Scala plugin forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/scala

Comment: You're right. Probably shouldn't have posted here.  Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar behavior in Netbeans IDE, when one of the libraries (Lift in particular) was depending on Scala 2.7.7 (not Scala 2.8). When scala-lang library 2.7.7 was on a class-path, that was somehow breaking the Scala support in Netbeans at all.
So check your PATH system variable, and the classpath.